# Dell PowerEdge 2900 with a faulty disk (among a Raid 5 array). Can I replace it with one with a different firmware?

Tags: dell-poweredge, raid5

The original Seagate ST3146855SS disk is running firmware 515, while the one I'm going to buy has a more recent firmware.
All other features are the same (15K5, 146Gb)

Will the controller just rebuild the RAID once I replace that disk?

Comment: To clarify what I think SmallLoan is saying below: Buy the disk and place it into the array and let the array rebuild. Then upgrade the firmware on the rest of your disks - hopefully your array will allow you to do this in-situ without removing the disks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will rebuild. However, it is best to match the firmware on your drives so they behave consistently during things like SCSI reset.